# What is the Java Edition seed for Minecraft's cover art?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you play Minecraft, there is an excellent chance that you've seen this picture before:
[image]

This image is Minecraft's cover art. Just recently, I've been starting to wonder: is there a seed for this picture? While some of the structures seen in this picture are hand-built, the rest of the terrain looks very natural. It would be very weird if someone built all of this by hand. Mojang just probably generated a world, built some stuff, and screenshotted this picture while on a mountain in 3rd person before letting it run through a software that makes this image like this and not like what vanilla Minecraft would look like. They might've also used a texture pack and some mods to take this screenshot. They might have used a software to make this screenshot, but it would've taken a long time to do so, so there is a very low chance of that being the case. I'm just curious - is there a seed for this world, or is there a world for this picture so that we can recreate the picture or play on this world?

Comment: I’d guess that this was art and not some kind of shaders and editing on a world, but also isn’t this the bedrock logo? I’m pretty sure this is the bedrock logo as its the logo of Minecraft Bedrock on PlayStation 4 at least.

Comment: The only way we know of to brute-force these seeds takes ages. Try asking the [Minecraft@Home](https://minecraftathome.com/minecrafthome/) people.

Comment: SalC1's discord is where people involved in seed cracking congregate. https://discord.salc1.com/  The Minecraft@Home team cooperates with them, but they'd send you there to get the project started anyway, and contribute the CPU time later once the groundwork is done.

Comment: @Penguin The foreground and middle-plane are art, but the far background seems to be regular Minecraft.

Comment: I am voting to close this question since this is might not actually be a seed at all and answers might be opinions to this image.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the title screen, the seed is 2151901553968352745 to see the title screen for real in Minecraft and interact with it. The cover art is just art, as @SF stated. The background is actual Minecraft, though we don't know the seed for the background. I hope this helped.